# Spec is failing on the same hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rspec

In my app I have few specs that depend on distracting some dates:

```
survey_instance.created_at + 1.day
```

then I check if collection of survey_instances have proper size. But this specs fails always at 3 a.m. How can I distract dates to avoid that problem?

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) was invented!

> A gem providing "time travel" and "time freezing" capabilities, making it dead simple to test time-dependent code. It provides a unified method to mock Time.now, Date.today, and DateTime.now in a single call.

Bundle it and change your spec to something like:

```
Timecop.freeze(2015, 10, 21, 10, 5, 0) do
  # whatever your assertion is
end
```

This will make sure this test will always run at the same time of day.

Comment: This is great solution but I thinking about solving this problem without using any new gem.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Why on earth would you want to deprive yourself of one of the great advantages of Ruby and open source in general?

Comment: I've decided  to create test object with predefined created_at. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański fixtures/factories with predefined attrs are a perfectly fine solution of course!